# Laravel 5.6 render mails from custom path not default views path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to load blade templates from a different path than the default resource path. But I keep getting the error:

> View [request.nlEmailTemplateTreatment] not found.

My path where the email template is stored:

```
root/storage/app/emails/request/nlEmailTemplateTreatment.blade.php
```

In the config/view.php I added this:

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
    realpath(storage_path('app/emails/request'))
],
```

In my Mailable class I do this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('somerandomeemail@gmail.com')
                ->view('request.nlEmailTemplateTreatment');
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, I cleared cache with:

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
->view('request.nlEmailTemplateTreatment');
```

to

```
->view('nlEmailTemplateTreatment');
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel expects to find the blade view template in your resources directory. Something like: `resources/views/emails`

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade):
'Blade view files use the  .blade.php file extension and are typically stored in the resources/views directory.'

Comment: The OP added an additional path in `config/view.php`.